# Bridging two ports with netcat/socat

Tags: networking, port, modbus, netcat, bridge

I need to get data from a ModBus device (modbus slave) over TCP but this device has to be exposed as a TCP client (it eats much less from the battery in this case). It means that both machines have to connect to the third one as TCP clients an I have to build a bridge between two ports, something like this

```
[modbus slave] -> [4444:bridge:5555] <- [modbus master]
```

I did try it with the netcat on a bridge machine

```
$ /bin/netcat -lk 5555 | /bin/netcat -lk 4444
```

It works the half way: I can connect to 4444 with my slave and to 5555 with my master, and traffic flows from master to slave. However, I do not see any traffic in the opposite direction. How do I build a two-way bridge in this case?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can run 2 netcat instances with a fifo like this:

```
# mkfifo fifo
# nc -l -p 4444 < fifo | nc -l -p 5555 > fifo
```

You can also do it using just socat.

```
# socat TCP4-LISTEN:4444 TCP4-LISTEN:5555
```

On a side note, I would imagine running a client consumes more power (which needs to keep on connecting) than server (which only waits for incoming connection). Maybe there is some other design consideration that I missed.

Comment: Yeah,  I have tried socat already with this 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:4444,fork,reuseaddr TCP4-LISTEN:5555,fork,reuseaddr'. It falls off sometimes, though.